# 502 Bad Gateway nginx for a drupal sub-directory site install

Tags: multi-sites, .htaccess

I have a default drupal 8 site install and a sub directory site install. The second Drupal site was an after thought and had to be hosted on the default site url in a sub folder. both sites share the same database with the second site having a prefix for its tables.

The issue i am experiencing with the second site, the landing page works perfectly but any other page gives an issue, oddly enough when i view on incognito the other pages work but when i refresh i get the 502 Bad Gateway error.

folder structure is as follows

```
htdocs
 - core
 - libraries
 - modules
 - node_modules
 - profiles
 - sites
 - themes (custom default theme here)
 - vendor
 - site2 (where i installed the second site with its own custom theme)
 - default drupal files (index.php, .htaccess ....)
```

I didn't change anything in both .htaccess files, i also tried in site2 .htaccess uncommented and updated the RewriteBase /site2 but still get the 502.

If someone could point me to the right direction regarding this issue, i have googled and tried numerous changes to the .htaccess files.

Comment: In all likelihood a 502 won't be related to anything in .htaccess. It generally means that the backend process (FPM) crashed before sending a valid response to the web server. It's a common problem that in my experience is rarely, if ever, caused by Drupal itself, rather mis-configuration of the FPM process, not enough memory, or something of that ilk. You'll find some troubleshooting pointers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252368/nginx-502-bad-gateway

Comment: Hi Clive, thanks for the feedback, would updating the memory limit also help in this regard as the memory limit is set to 128M.

Comment: It certainly could do, but it's difficult to get a good idea without being in front of the machine with the problem

Comment: Hi Clive, I think this might be a prob with the system admin that handles our server. Thanks once again..

Comment: Hi Clive, just some weird thing that was happening on the live server. The page that was giving issues was a form page, so what i ended up doing, i added the form fields on-by-one and when i added all 16 fields, it gave the above error. So i ended up having 12 fields the page worked and form submitted, will investigate this issue.